# upgrade angularjs 1.2 to 1.3 directive ng-repeat scope issue

Tags: angularjs, directive

Currently trying to update from angularjs 1.2 to 1.3 and have discovered a problem. The app has a paging directive:

```
app.directive("mobilePaginationList", function() {
 return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: "Directives/mobilePagination/List/mobilePaginationList.html",
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            list: '=list'
        },
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attributes) {
            // code removed that is not relevant
            $scope.listToDisplay = PaginationService.from(origList).getPage(page);
        }
    }

}
```

template is:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div data-ng-repeat="currentItem in listToDisplay"  bindonce data-ng-transclude>
        </div>
        <mobile-pagination-pager data-ng-hide="vm.list.length <= 0"></mobile-pagination-pager>
    </div>
</div>
```

usage example:

```
<mobile-pagination-list data-receipt-slider-menu-toggle="active" list="receipts" data-ng-hide="list.length <= 0 || rootVm.loading.receipts.value" class="row list-group">
        <a class="row list-group-item" data-bo-id="currentItem.attachNo" ui-sref="receiptWalletDetails({receiptId: currentItem.attachNo})">
            <div class="col-xs-11">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <h4 data-bo-bind="currentItem.description"></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">
                        <h4 data-bo-bind="currentItem.amount | currency:''"></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item-text">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                            <span data-bo-bind="currentItem.notes"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">
                            <span class="text-info"
                                data-bo-bind="currentItem.createDate | date: 'd MMM yyyy'">
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </mobile-pagination-list>
```

What is happening is that the ng-repeat is correctly displaying the number rows but each row does not contain any data from the currentItem object. The row does contain all the HTML but is missing currentItem values.

I have done quite a few searches into this problem but yet to find a solution.

Cheers

Comment: What is the data-bo-bind attribute and what does it do?

Comment: I doubt the issue is angular. Since you are upgrading why not 1.5 instead of 1.3 or for that matter any other later version?

Comment: data-bo-bind attribute is part of the bindonce directive that was useful in the early days of angularjs - plan on removing it as I upgrade to the latest version of angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to include $parent before currentItem. Something like below

**Usage:**

```
<mobile-pagination-list data-receipt-slider-menu-toggle="active" list="receipts" data-ng-hide="list.length <= 0 || rootVm.loading.receipts.value" class="row list-group">

    <a class="row list-group-item" data-bo-id="$parent.currentItem.attachNo" ui-sref="receiptWalletDetails({receiptId: currentItem.attachNo})">
        <div class="col-xs-11">

          <h4 ng-bind="$parent.currentItem.description"></h4>
          <h4 ng-bind="$parent.currentItem.amount | currency:''"></h4>
          <span ng-bind="$parent.currentItem.notes"></span>
          <span class="text-info" ng-bind="$parent.currentItem.createDate | date: 'd MMM yyyy'">
          </span>

        </div>
    </a>
</mobile-pagination-list>
```

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SSmi8aHpRuvNqOLWGwCh) with a working example.

Please note that your code is modified to get rid of dependencies.